# how can I get the Final Url Suffix via Search Ads 360 API

Tags: google-api, google-api-python-client

I am using the Search Ads 360 API in order to get insights of campaigns created via Search Ads 360 tool.

I am developing in python and I use googleapis library to request my reports. I am able to request a lot of reports types, metrics and dimensions thanks to the [SA360 API documentation](https://developers.google.com/search-ads/v2/report-types) but I don't know how to get the "**Final Url Suffix**" that I see on the tool (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lY7HV.png)) with the API.

For example, I am requesting the API with the following columns in the body:

```
[
    {"columnName": "date"},
    {"columnName": "status"},
    {"columnName": "agency"},
    {"columnName": "agencyId"},
    {"columnName": "advertiser"},
    {"columnName": "advertiserId"},
    {"columnName": "account"},
    {"columnName": "accountId"},
    {"columnName": "campaign"},
    {"columnName": "campaignId"},
    {"columnName": "impr"},
    {"columnName": "clicks"},
    {"columnName": "ctr"}
]
```

Does anyone know how to get "**Final Url Suffix**" with the api?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Same question for the element "**Division.ID**" in the tool but less important than "Final Url Suffix"

Comment: Have you found a solution, please? Facing the same issue

Comment: Not working on it anymore, sorry! I didn't find any solution